# Updating quantity of multiple field from selections using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm updating quantities in an order form with predefined "packs" from the database. Updating the from fields from the "packs" dropdown in the first function works, but the second function that uses those values and multiplies them by the value in a text input does not update the fields.

Also, when looking at the console output, it looks like the ajax request from the first and second function both run when the quantity input is changed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $("[id^=packs]").on('change', function() {
        var packname = this.value;
        console.log("packname:"+packname);
        var lineno = this.getAttribute('data-lineno');
        console.log("lineno: "+lineno);
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/pack",
            cache: false,
           // ContentType : 'application/json',
            data: {name: packname},
            success: function(json){
            try{
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                console.log(obj);
                console.log("size1: "+obj.packdetail[0].size1);

                    $('#'+lineno+'-size1').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size1);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size2').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size15);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size3').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size2);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size4').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size25);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size5').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size3);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size6').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size35);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size7').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size4);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size8').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size45);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size9').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size5);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size10').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size55);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size11').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size6);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size12').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size65);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size13').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size7);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size14').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size75);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size15').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size8);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size16').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size85);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size17').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size9);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size18').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size95);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size19').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size10);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size20').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size105);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size21').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size11);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size22').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size115);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size23').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size12);
                    $('#'+lineno+'-size24').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size125);

            }
            catch(e) {
                console.log('Exception while request..');
            }},
            error: function(){
                console.log('Error while request..');
            }
     });

    });

    //multiply packs

    $("[id^=packs_qty]").on('change', function() {
    var pack_qty = this.value;
    var packname = $(this).attr("data-name");
    console.log("qty:"+pack_qty);
    console.log("packname:"+packname);
    var lineno = this.getAttribute('data-lineno');
    console.log("lineno: "+lineno);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/pack",
        cache: false,
       // ContentType : 'application/json',
        data: {name: packname},
        success: function(json){
        try{
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
            console.log(obj);
            console.log("size1: "+obj.packdetail[0].size1*pack_qty);

                $('#'+lineno+'-size1').attr("value", (obj.packdetail[0].size1*pack_qty));
                $('#'+lineno+'-size2').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size15*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size3').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size2*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size4').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size25*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size5').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size3*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size6').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size35*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size7').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size4*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size8').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size45*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size9').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size5*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size10').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size55*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size11').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size6*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size12').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size65*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size13').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size7*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size14').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size75*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size15').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size8*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size16').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size85*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size17').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size9*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size18').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size95*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size19').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size10*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size20').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size105*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size21').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size11*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size22').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size115*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size23').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size12*pack_qty);
                $('#'+lineno+'-size24').attr("value", obj.packdetail[0].size125*pack_qty);

        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log('Exception while request..');
        }},
        error: function(){
            console.log('Error while request..');
        }
 });

});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please convert `obj.packdetail[0].size1` and `pack_qty` in to Number and try,
for this you can use

```
parseInt(obj.packdetail[0].size1) * parseInt(pack_qty);
```

Please have a try..